# Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL" in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shiny application to show boxplot or scatter plot. when i clicked "Run App" button in R studio, it shows error:

> runApp('temp')
> Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "NULL". What does it mean?
>
> I am a beginner in Shiny. I used the example on "https://shiny.posit.co/" as a template.

## helper_functions.R

```
color_code <- function(x) {
  switch(x,
         Gender = c("#ff0000", "#4472c4"),
         AgeGroup = c("20yr_29yr" = "#c5e0b4", 
                      "30yr_39yr" = "#b4c7e7", 
                      "40yr_49yr" = "#f8cbad", 
                      "50yr_59yr" = "#c55a11", 
                      "60yr_69yr" = "#bf9000", 
                      "70yr_80yr" = "#7030a0",
         ),
         NULL
  )
```

## dataframe.R

```
df <- df_combine   |> 
  mutate(across(
    -c(ID, Gender, AgeGroup),
    ~ if_else(is.na(.), NA, as.numeric(.))
  ))
```

> head(df)
>
> ID Gender  Age  AgeGroup    SIN  HK JP  AST
>
> 1 IDK0001 Female 31.6 30yr_39yr  39  46  19  18
>
> 2 IDK0002 Female 29.6 20yr_29yr  47  45  13  20
>
> 3 IDK0003 Female 75.2 70yr_80yr  43  59  11  19
>
> 4 IDK0004  Male 56.6 50yr_59yr  43  76  37  24
>
> 5 IDK0005 Female 42.8 40yr_49yr  43  39  17  17
>
> 6 IDK0006 Female 75.0 70yr_80yr  43 102  17  19

## ==== ui.R ====

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "minty"),
  titlePanel("Travel history"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("graphType", "Select Graph Type:", choices = c("scatter", "box"), selected = "scatter"),
      selectInput("x_var", "Select X Variable", choices = names(df)[-1]), 
      selectInput("y_var", "Select Y Variable", choices = names(df)[-1]),# [-c(1:4)]
      hr(),
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "gender", "Filter by Gender",
        choices = unique(df$Gender), 
        selected = unique(df$Gender)
      ),
      checkboxInput("by_gender", "Show gender", TRUE),
      checkboxInput("show_margins", "Show marginal plots", TRUE),
      checkboxInput("smooth", "Add smoother lines"),
      checkboxInput("stat_test", "Add p-value and R"),
      
      # Download button
      downloadButton("downloadPlot", "Download graph")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1",
                 dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",
                 brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush", resetOnNew = TRUE)), # resetOnNew = TRUE cannot brush with dense data (sth do with nearpoint?)
      tableOutput("brush_info")
    )
  )
)
```

## server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  subsetted <- reactive({
    req(input$gender) 
    df |> filter(Gender %in% input$gender) 
  })
  
  
  # Single zoomable plot
  ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL) 
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(subsetted(), aes(!!input$x_var, !!input$y_var)) +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
      theme_bw()
    
    if (input$graphType %in% "scatter") {
      p <- p +
        list(
          if (input$by_gender) aes(color = Gender),
          geom_point(alpha = 0.5),
          if (input$smooth) geom_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, se = TRUE),
          if (input$stat_test) ggpubr::stat_cor(),
          scale_color_manual(values = color_code(input$gender))
          
        )
    } else if (input$graphType %in%  "box") { # not always colored by gender in this case
      p <- p +
        list(
          geom_boxplot(
            color = "black", fill = "white", width = 0.5,
            size = 1.0, outlier.shape = NA, coef = 1.5
          ),
          geom_jitter(aes(color = input$x_var), width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5),
          scale_color_manual(values = color_code(input$x_var))
        )
    }
    
    if (input$show_margins) {
      margin_type <- if (input$by_gender) "density" else "histogram"
      p <- ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = margin_type, margins = "both",
                               size = 8, groupColour = input$by_gender, groupFill = input$by_gender)
    }
    
    p + coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y, expand = FALSE)
  }, res = 100) 
  
  output$brush_info <- renderTable({
    brushedPoints(subsetted(), input$plot1_brush)
  })

  
  observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot1_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }
  })

  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {
      
      paste(input$xvar, ".png", sep = "")
      
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      
      ggsave(df, plot = plot1, device = "png")
      
    }
    
  )
}
```

Comment: It's still crashed after adding dplyr. I got library(tidyverse) already

Comment: your `color_code` helper appears to expect a length-1 string input with possible values of "Gender" or "AgeGroup".  Try running `sapply(c("Female","Male"), color_code)` and review the output - is that your expected behaviour?

Comment: I tried. No graph is shown in shiny. The error is Warning: Error in brushedPoints: brushedPoints: not able to automatically infer `xvar` from brush

Comment: I meant try running that code alone, not as part of your program.

Comment: You have only one use of `filter` in your code: `df |> filter(Gender %in% input$gender) ` in the `subsetted` reactive.  The error message suggest to me that `df` is not defined.